# Convert ArrayList to Observable List for JavaFX program?

Tags: arraylist, javafx, combobox, observablelist

I am a semi-beginner Java programmer, learning Java FX from a variety of sources.  In my program, I would like to create a ComboBox, and populate the choices with the toString() output of a series of objects from an ArrayList.  Here, pizza toppings are defined as an object.  They are created and stored in a PizzaMgr object, basically a glorified wrapper for an ArrayList:

```
public class Topping{

  private String name;

  public Topping(String a){
    this.name=a;
  }
  public String toString(){
    return this.name;
  }
}

//=================================================

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PizzaMgr{

  private ArrayList<Topping> OrderedToppings;

  public PizzaMgr(){
      OrderedToppings = new ArrayList<Topping>();
      OrderedToppings.add(new Topping("Pepperoni"));
      OrderedToppings.add(new Topping("Mushrooms"));
      OrderedToppings.add(new Topping("Onions"));
  }

  public ArrayList<Topping> getList(){
      return OrderedToppings;
  }
}
```

So far, so good.  But the hitch I hit is when I want a ComboBox to list all of those items in the PizzaMgr's ArrayList.  Ideally, I'd like to use this ComboBox constructor:

```
ComboBox<T>(ObservableList<T> items)
```

The problem?  How to extract all the ArrayList items into an Observable List?  I've been reading up on Arraylists, Observable Lists, interfaces in general, but I can't figure out how to get this to work.  I've read that an ArrayList is a Collection, and Observable List can be an interface to a Collection, so I thought I was home free.  However, when I try to implement the ComboBox constructor:

```
import javafx.scene.control.*;

public class Menu{

  public static void main(String[] args){
      PizzaMgr m = new PizzaMgr();
      ComboBox<Topping> topMenu = new ComboBox<Topping>(m.getList());
  }
}
```

I get the compiler error:

```
Menu.java:18: error: incompatible types: ArrayList<Topping> cannot be converted to ObservableList<Topping>
            ComboBox<Topping> topMenu = new ComboBox<Topping>(m.getList());
                                                                       ^
```

So obviously my ArrayList isn't seen as an Observable List.

What stumps me is: How can I present my ArrayList to the ComboBox constructor, making it seem like an Observable List?  Is it a syntax slight-of-hand?  Or do I have to convert the ArrayList into another data structure in advance?

Many thanks,
-RAO

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ObservableList` is a sub interface (specialized version of) `List`. (`ObservableList` adds functionality for observing changes to the list.) `ArrayList` is a particular implementation of `List`, but is not an implementation of `ObservableList`. Hence you can pass an `ArrayList` anywhere a `List` is expected, but you cannot pass an `ArrayList` if an `ObservableList` is expected.

As something of an aside, note it's not really recommended to expose the implementation type, but you should really just expose the interface type:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PizzaMgr{

  private List<Topping> orderedToppings;

  public PizzaMgr(){
      orderedToppings = new ArrayList<Topping>();
      orderedToppings.add(new Topping("Pepperoni"));
      orderedToppings.add(new Topping("Mushrooms"));
      orderedToppings.add(new Topping("Onions"));
  }

  public List<Topping> getList(){
      return orderedToppings;
  }
}
```

To create an `ObservableList` from a regular `List`, you can use

```
ComboBox<Topping> topMenu 
    = new ComboBox<Topping>(FXCollections.observableList(m.getList()));
```

which creates a new `ObservableList` that "wraps" the array list you provide. I.e. calling `get(index)` or `add(item)` on the observable list simply delegates to the list you provide.

You could also do

```
ComboBox<Topping> topMenu 
    = new ComboBox<Topping>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(m.getList()));
```

which would create a new observable list and copy all the elements from the list you provide into it. So subsequently manipulating one list would not change the other.

Comment: It works!!!  So awesome!!!  I'm over the moon right now, you have no idea.  Thanks a million, this is really great.  :)

Answer (score 5):

To create an `observableList` you need to, first of all, have a predefined list eg an `arrayList`. Pass the list to an instance of `observableList` as below...

```
//Assuming you had this for a list
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

//Pass it over in this manner

ObservableList<String> observableList = FXCollections.observableList(list);
//Then add a listener

observableList.addListener (new ListChangeListener() {
  //override the method here
}
```

Hope it will help...

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<Site> sites = new ArrayList < Site > ();

sites.add(new Site("Google", "http://www.google.com"));

ObservableList<Site> siteList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(sites);

final ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox(siteList);

Button btn = new Button();

btn.setText("Read comboBox");

btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler < ActionEvent > () {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        label.setText("selected: " + comboBox.getValue());

        Site site = (Site) comboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

        System.out.println(site.name);
    }
});
```